# Highcharts load 2 charts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm working with Highcharts and try pre-load two graphics on a tab bootstrap switch tabs to change the graph shown. The problem is that the first graphic load fine, but the second is not displayed. Now if I open the console of Firefox development, magically it appears (and correctly operate both tabs). I remember that this happened to me for years, but can not remember why it may be; I suspect it has something to do with a call to jQuery, any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does opening the Firefox development alter the window size? This could force a redraw, which could make the graph appear. Other than that, some code will be needed here to give exact advice.

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/0hw3zk5t/8/ ,while opening console window re-sizes and this event show you chart which was set as hidden by display none property in bootstrap class.

Comment: Just redraw! Thanks very much to Halvor Strand and  Nishith Kant Chaturvedi